# Find the issues of SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a questions from a test, it seems an concept question or logic question, so no data at all. Please read:

Assuming there's no syntax error and the column names and table names are correct, what's wrong with the MySQL query below?

-- FOR EVERY USER WE HAVE, this is supposed to return the number of messages they sent

```
select u.user_id, sum(case when um.message_id is not null then 1 else 0 end) as number_of_messages_sent
from users u left join
     users_messages um
     on um.user_id = u.user_id
where um.status = 'sent'
group by u.user_id;
```

If anyone have any ideas, please help me.

Comment: the `u.user_i` should be `u.user_id`. if you execute the above query as it is it will throw an error. either all need to be `u.user_id` or `u.user_i`

Answer (score 1):

The `where` clause is turning the `left join` into an `inner join`.  So it is only returning users who have sent at least one message.  That is not the intent of the question.

A better way to write the query uses `count()` and fixes the problem by moving condition to the `on` clause:

```
select u.user_id, count(um.message_id) as number_of_messages_sent
from users u left join
     users_messages um
     on um.user_id = u.user_id and um.status = 'sent'
group by u.user_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are filtering all results with status="sent". Final result is not "all users and masseges". Final result is "All users who sent one or many massages".

This query is all users and the if exists their massages

```
SELECT u.user_id, COUNT(um.message_id)
FROM users AS u, users_messages AS um 
WHERE um.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id;
```

This query will return Users who sent at least 1 massage. U will not see users who have not sent massage yet.

```
SELECT u.user_id, COUNT(um.message_id)
FROM users AS u, users_messages AS um 
WHERE um.user_id = u.user_id AND status="sent"
GROUP BY u.user_id;
```

Comment: I disagree. it is filtering all results with status = 'sent' but it is summing up all the sent messages. so the final result is NOT "all users who sent one or many messages" it is "number of messages they sent"

Comment: @O.KOO Yes but he uses left join which will remove null values (in right table). I think error occures when null presented in his query. In this query count will print 0 if there is nothing to count.

Comment: Agreed^ I changed my opinion after I made some sample table to test it out.

Comment: @Xiaoxi that SUM function will be executed for each row one by one presented to that function. If there is no row, function will not even run. So it can count if null is presented to it but after state=sent SUM will not even see the user to sum massages.

Answer (score 0):

The column in the `select` query is `u.user_i` and the column in the `group by` is `u.user_id`

Answer (score 0):

**What Went Wrong:**

your query supposes to get *EVERY* user we have but it is only returning user who has sent messages. This is because your `WHERE` clause filtered out the users who didn't send any messages. Let me illustrate this with an example.

**Example:**

I made some sample table with data using this code:

```
CREATE TABLE userz (
  user_id int,
) ;

INSERT INTO userz (user_id)
VALUES
(1),(2),(3)

CREATE TABLE userz_messages(
  message_id int,
  user_id int,
  status varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO userz_messages (message_id,user_id,status)
VALUES 
(1,1,'sent'),
(2,2,'sent'),
(3,3,'sent'),
(4,4,'notsend'),
(5,1,'sent'),
(6,2,'sent')
```

userz_table:

```
user_id
-----------
1
2
3
```

userz_message table:

```
message_id  user_id     status
----------- ----------- ----------
1           1           sent
2           2           sent
3           3           sent
4           4           notsend
5           1           sent
6           2           sent
```

when we perform your query we get this as the result:

```
user_id      number_of_messages_sent
----------- -----------------------
1           2
2           2
3           1
```

*Notice* user with user_id 4 is not in the result set? This is what's wrong with the query. It is not getting EVERY user.

Hope my example helps you get a better understanding of your problem

Comment: Thanks for your tips. I got your points, but the question's purpose is to return the number of messages they sent. So, it should not return every user.

Comment: but in your post, you said "for every user". Do you only want the user who sent out 1 or more messages and excludes users who have not sent any messages at all?

Comment: That is the description of the test, I did not change a word. I think the purpose is to return the number of messages they sent.

Comment: well. the current query is doing that exactly. returning total number of messages from the user who has at least sent one message.

Comment: @XiaoxiChen I think you might be getting confused. the query does return the number of messages user sent but the question is which users? the test asked "FOR EVERY" users. but the query is only returning a subset of users namely those who have at least sent 1 message. Therefore the query is not doing the description of the test. Does that make sense?